# Non blazor folders on blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I want a folder in a blazor project not to be handled by blazor, but using another handler. (not static files)

I understand this is related to routing

How this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of files do you need to process?

Comment: Create image files dynamicly from html, and to make them available as files.

Comment: have you sorted out the service that extracts the image files from the HTML? if so, you just need to put it(images) in the folder of your choice(wwwroot is the default folder where the StaticFilesMiddleware have access) but I'm guessing you don't want this to be accessed by the users instead of another system/service?

Comment: Is this for a Blazor web-assembly (WASM), or Blazor Server. The two have different approaches for creating dynamic content.

Comment: Blazor server. The images are generated dynamicly and not saved as files.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I was looking for:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/img/", async context =>
{
     await context.Response.WriteAsync(CallSomeHandler());
}
);
```